# How to identify different flavors of Markdown?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Given the many flavors of Markdown in existence, is there a way to identify different flavors, by content type or other attribute?

There is a general content type `text/markdown` as specified in [IETF RFC-7763](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7763), but that does not distinguish between different flavors.

For example, RSS uses `application/rss+xml` so is there something like `text/markdown+gfm` for GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Some flavors include:

- [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/)
- [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)
- [GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM)](https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/)
- [Ghost Markdown](https://docs.ghost.org/faq/using-the-editor/#using-markdown)

I did find the following thread but the result seems to be to not support disambiguation:

- https://talk.commonmark.org/t/ietf-request-for-input-text-markdown-media-type/700/12

Comment: No there is no formal way to identify different flavors.

Comment: @Waylan please consider posing your comment as an answer. You'll likely get points for it and then we won't see this as unanswered.